# If checkbox is checked, create cookie that expires in 1 year

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

I have a checkbox in my view:

<%= check_box_tag 'remember', '', false, :class => 'chkbx' %>

Now when the user clicks the 'submit' button, I need to:
1. create a cookie
2. set the expiration to 1 year from now **IF the user checked the checkbox.**

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if params[:remember]
  c = {:value => 'cookie-value'}
  if !params[:remember]
    c.merge(:expires => 1.years.from_now())
  end
  cookies[:cookie_name] = c
end
```

Comment: if the remember is not checked, I still need to create the cookie just w/o the expires.  is there a clean way of doing this w/o repeating the same line of code but w/o the :expires symbol?

Comment: You shouldn't make a cookie never expire. I'm pretty sure leaving out the :expires will just default to 2 weeks. A quick google search didn't yield much. I've edited the code to do what you described, but check to see if it defaults the cookie to 2 weeks. If you want the effect of never expiring, just set the expire time to 10 years, 100 years, something absurd.